# JQuery plug-in with on-click function inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a problem because I want run an on-click function inside my JQuery plug-in. In the code snippet you can see that the plug-in run since I try to click the button and nothing happen so I'm asking for a different way to include this on-click event function on my plug-in to make it run. Thank you in advance and sorry for my English.

```js
(function ( $ ) {
 
    $.fn.myPlugin = function( options ) {
 
        // Options
        var settings = $.extend({
            btnText: "Click me!",
            text: "text text text text text",
        }, options );
        
        // Html
        var html = "<div class='container'><p>"+settings.text+".</p><a alt='"+settings.btnText+"' class='btn'>"+settings.btnText+"</a></div>";
        
        // Open functions
        return $("body").append(html);
        
        // Close functions
        $(".btn").click(close);
        
        function close() {
             $(".container").remove();
        };
        
    };
    
}(jQuery));

// Start plugin
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).myPlugin({
        // Options
    });
});
```

```css
/* demo css */
a {
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the click listener is never added to your .btn, because that code is never executed. It's because you have a return:

```
return $("body").append(html);
```

so the code stops right there. It should only be

```
$("body").append(html);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, then how can i add this function on my plug-in?

Comment: @paolobasso I don't understand your question. If you remove that "return" from your code as I mentioned, your code works. See here for example: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4hpcLsoe/)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that return stop the functions then thank you.